# dotnet command doesnt work in jenkins (dotnet 6.0)

Tags: .net, linux, bash, jenkins

I'm not sure if its a bug or not, but dotnet command always worked for me in Jenkins, but after I updated dotnet to 6.0 it started giving me `"command not found"` error.

Command still works in terminal.

I tried doing `export PATH=/usr/share/dotnet:$PATH` (tried /local dir as well) and added it as a global path, but it didnt help.

I found that `export PATH=/usr/share/dotnet:$PATH` works only for the same session , so the only way I can run dotnet commands in Jenkins now is by adding the `export PATH=/usr/share/dotnet:$PATH` command at the start of the build. It shouldn't be this way though.

Anyone has suggestions for solving this?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104728/442609

Comment: I use jenkins and dotnet 6 And is working for me. If running jenkins on linux. I would ssh to it and switch to the user jenkins. That is the user used by the service. Then from the shell try to build anything. using dotnet command. If fail, add path to the user environment variables.
Once the user sees the command, so should the process.